# Expectation: sigmoid times mixture of Gaussians

Tags: expected-value, gaussian

Let $Y$ be a random variable where
\begin{align}
Y&=Z\theta^*+W
\end{align}
Here $Z$ is a Rademacher random variable, $W\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2 I_p)$, and $\theta\in \mathbb{R}^p$ is a fixed parameter. Marginalizing over $Z$ gives the density
\begin{align}
g_{\theta^*}(y)&=\frac{1}{2}\phi(y-\theta^*;\theta;\sigma^2 I_p)+\frac{1}{2}\phi(y+\theta^*;\theta;\sigma^2 I_p)
\end{align}
where $\phi(x;\mu,\Sigma)$ is the density of multivariate $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$.  I want to compute $\mathbb{E}\frac{1}{1+\exp(-\frac{2\theta^* TY}{\sigma^2})}Y$.  I believe from reading A.3 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.00519.pdf that this is equal to $\frac{\theta^*}{2}$.  I do
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\frac{1}{1+\exp(-\frac{2\theta^* TY}{\sigma^2})}Y
    &=\frac{1}{2}\int y\frac{1}{1+\exp(-\frac{2\theta^*T y}{\sigma^2})}\frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma)^{p/2}}\exp(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[\Vert y-\theta^*\Vert^2])dy\\
    &\qquad +\frac{1}{2}\int y\frac{1}{1+\exp(-\frac{2\theta^*T y}{\sigma^2})}\frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma)^{p/2}}\exp(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[\Vert y+\theta^*\Vert^2])dy
\end{align}
but then don't know how to proceed.